# Overloading postincrement

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a class `myClass` storing one `int`. I want to overload standard operators, like `+`, `=`, `+=`, `++` etc. How can I overload postfix increment, i.e. `operator++(int)`, so that the actual incrementation is done after the expression is evaluated? I mean, after the following code has bean executed,

```
myClass object1(0), object2(1);
object1 = object2++ + object2;
```

I want both object1 and object2 to hold 2.

The naive approach

```
myClass& operator++(int){
  myClass tmp(x) //x - stored value
  ++x;
  return tmp;
}
```

doesn't work, since `++` is called before `+`.

I've been looking for an answer to that, but found nothing relevant. Frankly, until recently I didn't think it was possible to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I suspect that any real world application that   wants to do this has major design issues and should be beaten over the head with a very big stick.

Comment: I don't understand, wouldn't `object1` and `object2` both hold `2` as post-increment is already executed after evaluating the statement?

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
myClass object1(0), object2(1);
object1 = object2++ + object2;
```

has actually unspecified behaviour, according to §8.3.6/9:

> The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

and due to the fact that that expression is converted to something like:

```
operator=(objec1, operator+(operator++(.., object2), object))
```

The obvious way to avoid this inconvenience is to perform the increment after the sum:

```
object1 = object + object2;
object++;
```

or (assuming `operator*` is also defined):

```
object1 = object2 * 2;
object++;
```

---

It would be undefined behaviour is they were of scalar types, according to §1.9/15:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [ Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently in different evaluations. — end note ] The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: If `object1` and `object2` were scalars, then you would be correct. But since these operators are function calls on class objects, the modification and the examination of the member x are not unsequenced, but indeterminately sequenced. So, not undefined behavior, but an implementation defined result.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley True.

Comment: He's asking how to avoid the unspecified behaviour

Comment: @MattMcNabb He is actually asking how to do something that is impossible to do without incurring in either undefined or unspecified behaviour in C++. The obvious way to define the proper order of elements is to have `object1 = object2 * 2;` and `object2++;` as two different statements.

Comment: @Jefffrey my answer explains how it is possible with well-defined behaviour. But my point was that you didn't address his question. Your answer explains how the existing code is unspecified but does not answer the question (either positively or negatively) of "How can I overload postfix increment, i.e. operator++(int), so that the actual incrementation is done after the expression is evaluated?"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments - this is a poor idea because the semantics of your code will not match the semantics of how `operator++` normally works, so other people looking at your code, and perhaps even yourself at a later date, will be confused.

To do it you would need to use a technique called *expression templates*. This isn't simple but the basic idea is that `operator++` and `operator+` (and any other operator) will return objects of a new type (say `Myclass_expr`) and that object builds up an expression as it goes; so the result of `x++ + x` will be a small tree that says "this expression means add x to x and then increment x". No actual arithmetic is performed yet.

Finally, the `Myclass_expr` will have a conversion operator to `Myclass` which contains the logic to traverse the stored expression and perform all the computations in the order that you want.

To see an example of this look at the Eigen matrix library.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found an ugly, but simple way to do this, so I'm posting it for future generations. I added a `myClass * ptr` field to `myClass`. It usually stores `nullptr`, except in an object returned by `operator++(int)`. In that case, `ptr` stores a pointer to the object that should be incremented. I also modified destructor, so that incrementation is executed when temporary object is destructed:

```
    myClass& operator++(int){
      myClass tmp(x);
      tmp.ptr = this;
      return tmp;
    }

    ~myClass(){
      if(ptr != nullptr)
        ++ptr->x;
    }
```

Although it's not standardized, `tmp` is usually destructed when semicolon is reached, i.e. when `x++ + x + x;` is executed, incrementation is done after the sum has been computed.

Answer (score 0):

```
myClass object1(0), object2(1);
object1 = object2++ + object2;
```

is analogous to:

```
int i1 = 0; i2 = 1;
i1 = i2++ + i2;
```

which is not guaranteed to produce a deterministic value. Evaluation of `i2++` and `i2` are not guaranteed to be from left to right. Depending on which gets evaluated first, the RHS of that expression can evaluate to `3` or `2`.

You should rethink your code.

Make it:

```
object1 = object2;
object1 += (object2++);
```

or

```
object1 = (object2++);
object1 += object2;
```

depending on what your intentions are.

Comment: @Jefffrey, if `i2++` gets evaluated first, then `i2++ + i2` will produce `4`. As you said in your answer, it really is UB.

Comment: If `object2++` gets evaluated before `object2` then `object2` (the second one after `+`) will become `2` and the result will be `3` instead of `2`.

Comment: @Jefffrey, `i2++ + i2` will evaluate to `3` o `2` depending on which term gets evaluated first. You are right about that.

Comment: It's not analogous because the `int` version causes undefined behaviour and the class version doesn't